# R code: When I draw a line graph including multiple lines in R, one of them cannot fully be displayed

Tags: r, plot, graph

[image]

I need a graph including three lines and one of them has different y-axes.
I wonder why the blue line is so short here? This is my code:

```
library(plotrix)

a <- c(41.995 ,41.749, 41.484, 41.200 ,40.898, 40.587, 40.274 ,39.968, 39.672, 39.388, 39.108 ,38.822,
38.521 ,38.202, 37.866, 37.528, 37.205, 36.909 ,36.643 ,36.401, 36.167 ,35.918, 35.631 ,35.289,
34.886 ,34.418, 33.890, 33.320, 32.726, 32.121, 31.517 ,30.924, 30.348, 29.792, 29.258, 28.749,
28.262, 27.789 ,27.324, 26.861, 26.401, 25.944 ,25.489, 25.034 ,24.571 ,24.087 ,23.564 ,22.996,
22.390 ,21.755 ,21.114 ,20.495 ,19.923 ,19.416 ,18.984 ,18.625 ,18.332 ,18.083)
b<-c(1960:2017)
c<-c(22.184, 21.652, 21.126, 20.608, 20.096, 19.591 ,19.093, 18.603, 18.122, 17.650, 17.187 ,16.730,
16.280, 15.838, 15.408 ,14.994, 14.601, 14.233 ,13.892, 13.577, 13.290, 13.027 ,12.786 ,12.558,
12.337, 12.117, 11.888 ,11.649, 11.398, 11.135 ,10.864, 10.588, 10.316 ,10.055,  9.808,  9.579,
9.370  ,9.179 , 9.003  ,8.841,  8.692 , 8.555  ,8.427 , 8.306 , 8.189 , 8.074  ,7.958 , 7.839,
7.720  ,7.602 , 7.492  ,7.393 , 7.312 , 7.251  ,7.212  ,7.194  ,7.195 , 7.210)
d<-c(5.906, 5.902, 5.894, 5.880 ,5.859, 5.830 ,5.794, 5.751 ,5.702, 5.648 ,5.587, 5.519 ,5.444, 5.363,
5.278 ,5.192, 5.108, 5.029 ,4.956, 4.889 ,4.827 ,4.766 ,4.703, 4.636 ,4.563 ,4.484, 4.399 ,4.311,
4.222 ,4.132, 4.045, 3.959 ,3.877 ,3.799 ,3.723 ,3.651 ,3.582 ,3.514 ,3.446, 3.379 ,3.311 ,3.244,
3.176 ,3.109, 3.041, 2.972, 2.899 ,2.823, 2.743 ,2.661, 2.581 ,2.506, 2.439 ,2.381, 2.333 ,2.295,
2.266 ,2.243 )

df1<- data.frame(Year=b,CBR=a,CDR=c,TFR=d)

twoord.plot(lx=df1$Year,ly=df1$CBR,rx=df1$Year,ry=df1$TFR,type = "l",xaxs='i',xticklab =c(1960:2019,by=3),xtickpos =c(1960:2019,by=3),xlab = "Year", ylab = "Number",main = 'R')
grid()
lines(b,c ,type = "l", col = "blue")
```

Comment: `twoord.plot` isn't a standard R function, can you add information about what other packages you are using? Looks like `plotrix`, maybe?

Comment: As for the issue, it looks like the y limits for the plot are set as soon as you call `twoord.plot`, based on teh range of the `CBR` and `TFR` columns. When you add `CDR`, which has a wider range, it's too late to adjust the plot  boundaries. Looking at `?twoord.plot`, you can customize the initial range with `lylim` and `rylim`. Make it big enough to include the `CDR` values.

Comment: Though I'm not sure which axis you want to plot them on, or how to pick. Two-axis  plots are problematic for this reason...

Answer (score 0):

Hi welcome to Stackoverflow, in the future please include the library call which has any none base R functions that you use.

The below gives you what you want

```r
library(plotrix)

ypos <- seq(from = 0, to = 50, by = 5)

twoord.plot(lx=df1$Year,ly=df1$CBR,rx=df1$Year,ry=df1$TFR,type = "l",xaxs='i'
            ,xticklab =c(1960:2019,by=3),xtickpos =c(1960:2019,by=3),xlab = "Year",
            ylab = "Number",main = 'R', lytickpos = ypos, lylim = c(0,50))
grid()
lines(x= df1$Year, df1$CDR, type = "l", col = "blue")
```

The blue line is small because some of its values are off the chart. This is because when the limits are picked automatically, `CDR` is excluded so adding it later with `lines()` plots only the values above 18, which is only prior to 1970 for `CDR`.

I've passed the `lylim` as 0 to 50 and I've also added the `lytickpos` as going from 0 to 50 in increments of 5.

Although this answers your question, this graph makes no sense to me.